# The difference between Due to and Thanks to

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

is there a difference between using expressions "due to" and "thanks to"? Сan I use it interchangeably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge "*thanks to*" has always a positive connotation while "*due to*" is more neutral and can have a negative connotation.

> **Thanks to** my good friend Ellen, I got to the airport on time
>
> The game was delayed **due to** bad weather.
>
> My desire to act was **due to** Laurence Olivier's performance in 'Hamlet'.

Comment: Except when being sarcastic (of course).

Answer (score 0):

Since both mean as a result of you could use them interchangeably in most cases but *due to* sounds more serious and describes the cause of something maybe in a more neutral way. For example using thanks to in the sentence below wouldn't sound quite right.

> his death was not **due to** any lack of care

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers provided, I would add that "due to" has a more impersonal tone. One generally would use "thanks to" for referring to people, e.g. "thanks to my boss I can afford food" vs. "due to my boss I can afford food".